# react setInterval not updating useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, setinterval

I am creating a digital clock where the time changes every second. You can set the time for when the digital clock starts from with the component. It's not currently working though, the time appears but doesn't update it's just static

If I do this it does however `const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());`

it does work but it causing a blink for 1 second while the date updates to the currentDate.

```
import './ActiveDate.scss';

interface ActiveDateProps {
    hours: number;
    mins: number;
    seconds: number;
}

const ActiveDate: React.FC<ActiveDateProps> = (props) => {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setHours(props.hours, props.mins, props.seconds);

    const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>(currentDate);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => setDate(currentDate), 1000 )
        return function cleanup() {
            clearInterval(timer)
        }
    });

    return (
        <>
            <p className="active-date">{date.toUTCString().substr(17, 8)}</p>
        </>
    )
  }

export default ActiveDate;
```

Comment: you forget `useEffect`'s second parameter, so `useEffect` will run on every render

Comment: I need it to run every render otherwise the time won't update. I.e I will have to refresh to see the seconds go up

Comment: I think it just may be a clunky implementation. https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-blackwell-h0kyt?file=/src/App.js